# navigation is not displaying correctly in IE

Tags: html, css

i tried ..

```
<!--[if IE 7 ]>
    <link href="http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8 ]>
    <link href="http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

**CSS**

```
header{
    position: relative;
    background:#7a2652;
    height: 75px;
}
header #telephone {
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: auto !important;
}
header #telephone p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2px;
    color: #fff;
}
header #telephone img {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

/*
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- nav
*/

nav#primary-menu {
    height: 37px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 38px;
    width: 685px;
    list-style: none outside none;
}

nav#primary-menu div {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #833B5D;
    float: right;
    height: 37px;
    margin-left: 32px;
    width: 645px;
}

nav#primary-menu ul#menu-mainnav {
    list-style: none outside none;
}

nav#primary-menu ul#menu-mainnav li {
    height: 37px;
    margin: 0 -10px 0 -37px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-left: 37px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none outside none;
}

nav#primary-menu ul#menu-mainnav li:hover:last-child {
    background: url("images/nav-last-bg.png") no-repeat transparent;
}

nav#primary-menu ul#menu-mainnav li:first-child {
    background: url("images/nav-first-bg.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
}       

nav#primary-menu ul#menu-mainnav li:hover {
    background: url("images/nav-current-bg.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
}

nav#primary-menu ul#menu-mainnav li.current-menu-item {
    background: url("images/nav-current-bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}

nav#primary-menu a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 9px;
    line-height: 120%;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 60px;
}

nav#primary-menu a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

nav#primary-menu a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

nav#primary-menu ul#menu-mainnav li ul.sub-menu {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
```

but and try to add some css, but nothing is happening, please tell me what do ..

the website is looking good in firefox but totally messed up in IE. please help me how i can sort this in IE.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp51g.jpg

please check the above image and guide me how can i solve the issue.

Comment: We would need to see your markup and CSS

Comment: yes, we need code. It could be just your Cache that's keeping an older version of the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `HTML5` elements which are supported by IE.

Use this js http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/ for `HTML5` Tag support for IE.

Comment: This is right, IE doesn't know what to with '<header>' or '<nav>' among others.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, quirks mode is triggered because the page contains many HTML and CSS errors. That messes up your page.
Check your website with the [W3C HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/) and fix these errors.

Comment: there r total 4 style sheets. style.css, theme.css, ie7.css and ie8.css.. these ie stylesheets are empty right now, but 2 stylesheets are working now

Comment: Edited my answer due to new insights

Answer (score 0):

You're using HTML5, use this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```